# How to trigger an events by django when html buttons are cliked

Tags: python, html, django

here is the html file form

```
<form action ="fetch" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="t1">
    <input type="text" name="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="b1">
    <input type="submit" name="b2">
</form>
```

now when we click on submit button its properly calls the fetch function 
but when i click on cancel button same fetch function is called so i don't want that to happen i want to trigger different event/function when user click's on cancel button

here is the html file form

```
<form action ="fetch" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="t1">
    <input type="text" name="t2">
    <input type="submit" name="b1">
    <input type="submit" name="b2">
</form>
```

my views.py

```
def fetch(request):

    a = request.GET.get("t1")
    b = request.GET.get("t2")
   return render(request,'student.html')
```

Comment: change type cancel to type button

Comment: There is no such thing as `input type="cancel"` in HTML. Also, the reason why your "cancel" button is calling the fetch method is that the button is inside a `<form>` linked to `fetch`.

Comment: what is in `urls.py`?

Comment: yes thanks guys that was typo

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. Just add the same `name` to each submit button with different values:

```html
<form action="/fetch/" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="t1"/>
   <input type="text" name="t2"/>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="submit"/>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="cancel"/>
</form>
```

Then in your view, the `action` will be whatever button you clicked:

```py
def fetch(request):
    print('This is a', request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.POST.get("action")
        print('The action is', action)
    return render(request, 'student.html')
```

Comment: i try that on but when i printing the action than out put is None, why?

Comment: and i want to call different function when user clicks on cancel button

Comment: I've edited the code to add some "debugging". What do you see in the terminal?

Comment: its displaying :- None

Comment: It's hard to debug from a far, so please show me the exact output. "This is a POST",  "This action is None" ?